# style font css in html can not function

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I write style css in html, the style can not function, I want change the font size, font color, but nothing result, my font-size and color can not change

```
if (geoBarData != null && geoBarData[geoBarDataKeyName].length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geoBarData[geoBarDataKeyName].length; i++) {
        var arrLstProdak = geoBarData[geoBarDataKeyName][i].item_group_list;

        var BranchName = geoBarData[geoBarDataKeyName][i].name;
        var innerDiv = "<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-6'>";
        innerDiv += "<div class='panel panel-default' >";
        innerDiv += "<div class='panel-heading' style='background-color:white;'><span  id='title-combo-" + i + "' style='font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-weight:800;'>" + BranchName + "</span></div>";
        innerDiv += "<div class='panel-body'>";
        innerDiv += "<div id='combo_chart_div-" + i + "' style='height: 300px;'></div>";
        innerDiv += "</div>";
        innerDiv += "</div>";
        innerDiv += "</div>";
        $("#div_combo_group").append(innerDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the font size and color for all elements or a specific element?

Comment: Perhaps you could post a screen shot showing the inspector HTML of these elements after the code is parsed?

Comment: I am not getting any error with the code, it is showing results